# Google books api: how to show the title?

Tags: google-api, google-books

I'm trying to do an exercise where I need to have an AJAX feed for my webpage. As my website is about books I'm using the Google Books API. 
I cant figure out how to show the title of the book though. This is the code I have so far:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=:a';
       $.get(url, function(data,status){
console.log(data);
var intValue =data.totalitems;
var strOne =data.kind;

var items = data.items;
$.each(items, function( index, value) {
    console.log(value.title);
    $('#div1').append('<li><div>'+value.title+'</div></li>')  });
});

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

**JS**

```
$.each(data.items, function(entryIndex, entry){                    
var html = '<div class="results">';   
html += '<h3>' + ( entry.volumeInfo.title || '' )+ '</h3>';  
$(html).hide().appendTo(".result");
});
```

**html**

```
<div class="result"></div>
```